# MSBuild property and variable overloading

Tags: msbuild, overloading, build-script

Let's say I launch a build script, definition named `SampleScript` , specifying the parameter `/p:MyPrefix=Custom`. There is the following code in the script:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(BuildDefinitionName)=='SampleScript'">
    <MyPrefix>Default</MyPrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As I get, first MyPrefix is set to "Custom", then it's overloaded to "Default" (am I right?). If so, is there any way to make a user-specified parameter more prioritized, so it's not overloaded?

Comment: Have you tested this?  If I remember correctly, command-line set values in MSBuild do in fact take precedence over values in the project/targets file.

Comment: Why not use a condition? `<MyPrefix Condition=" '$(MyPrefix)' == '' ">Default</MyPrefix>`

Comment: @Nick - you are 100% right, tested it.

Comment: @KMoraz - that's not what I want, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only overload a property specified on the command line by dynamically changing the value inside a target...

```
<Project ...>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <Value>FromStaticProperty</Value>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="PropertyPrecedence">
      <Message Text="Value = '$(Value)'" />
      <PropertyGroup>
         <Value>FromDynamicProperty</Value>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <Message Text="Value = '$(Value)'" />
   </Target>
</Project>

> msbuild /p:Value=FromCommandLine
```

In the above example, the "FromStaticProperty" will be ignored given the value supplied from the command line, but the "FromDynamicProperty" will be used.

Excerpted from [MSBuild Trickery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061550907X) trick #27